# I want to override a few pieces of my CSS for mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile, overriding

I have a website that for the most part resizes correctly for mobile browsers. However there are a few items that I'd like to display in block format in mobile browsers. Is there a way to just override these areas with a mobile browser hack?

Comment: Yes, there is: [CSS media queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) Next question.

Comment: I've added the following to my CSS file: @media handheld { div.column3, div.column3last { display:block; } } but no changes have been made. The link to the site I'm working on is: talktothedogs.com/annkempa and the working on the very bottom section "Contact". When checking on my iPhone all the columns overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is mobile safari, it's your implementation of responsive design. Adjusting the width of the chrome window on my desktop causes the columns to overlap too. I would suggest adding an explicit min-width to your columns and floating them all left instead of having the last one float right.